# LinQ to SQL and where is the choice for all database

Tags: linq, entity-framework-6

I have the source code like this:

```
var res = from s in Splitting 
          join c in Customer on s.CustomerId equals c.Id
         where c.Id == customrId
            && c.CompanyId == companyId
        select s;
```

When reviewing code, one member said that my code applies for only one SQL db, and advised me to use LinQ to Entity with Join so that it will work for all databases.

I don't understand, I think, even with other db, we will add it to Entity Framework. And the code below will work correct too, right?

Please advise.

Comment: Is this query running in memory? Is your coworker talking about replacing `Splitting` and `Customer` with `queryContext.Splitting`/`queryContext.Customer`?

Comment: what they meant that by using query as above, it will not be used when we change db to others like Oracle, mySQL,...

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways you can write your **LINQ**.

1.[LINQ Query Expressions (query-syntax)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397676.aspx) (Which you have done)

```
var res = from s in Splitting 
          join c in Customer on s.CustomerId equals c.Id
         where c.Id == customrId
            && c.CompanyId == companyId
        select s;
```

2.Another is  [LINQ query extension methods (dot-syntax)](https://www.dotnetperls.com/join)

```
var res = Splitting.Join(Customer,
                 sp => sp.CustomerId,
                 cu => cu.Id,
                 (sp, cu) => new { sp, cu })
           .Where(s => s.cu.Id == customrId && s.cu.CompanyId == companId)
           .Select(s => s.sp);
```

> For joins, I strongly prefer **query-syntax**.There are details that
>   **query-syntax** hides that can make it well worth embracing with the improvement to readability it brings.However query-syntax is somewhat
>   more limited than **dot-syntax** in other aspects.
>
> **dot-syntax** is more concise but performing multiple table joins is a nightmare.The flip side is that there are a number of LINQ
>   operations that only exist within the **dot-syntax**: Single(),
>   First(), Count() etc.For these limitation of query-syntax you can use
>   dot-syntax.

N.B : At compile time, all are converted to Standard Query.

Comment: hi Ashiquzzaman,
With LinQ dot-syntax, if we want to change from SQL db to Oracle db, it will work correct too, right?

Comment: hi Ashiquzzaman, That is because we are working on Entity (.edmx) right? when execute in real, the Entity Framework will parse it to right select depend on which database?
Sorry for this inconvenience, I just ask because I want to know how EF work. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry , I can't understand what you  are asking.

Comment: thank, my question is, with my sample above, when check by SQL Profiler, we will see the SQL will transform to SQL syntax, right?
Same for Oracle, the Oracle also will transform to Oracle syntax?