# How to nested parsing expression .NET C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0, iqueryable

How to nested parsing expression ,I'm developing [an ORM](https://github.com/sunkaixuan/SqlSugar), who can help me with some ideas?

```
var list = db.Queryable<Student>()
    .Where(it => it.Id.Equals(db.Queryable<School>()
    .Where(sc => sc.Id == it.Id&&sc.Name=="jack"))).ToList()
```

Comment: Read into joins, or better navigation properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's batter to use LINQ joins for this purpose.

Example:

1| LINQ [query-syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397676.aspx)

```
var list = (from s in db.Student 
          join sc in db.School on s.SchoolId equals sc.Id
          where sc.Name=="jack"
         select s).ToList() ;
```

2| LINQ [Extension method](https://www.dotnetperls.com/join)

```
var list = db.Student.Join(db.School,
                 s => s.SchoolId,
                 sc => sc.Id,
                 (s, sc) => new { s, sc })
           .Where(ss => ss.sc.Name=="jack")
           .Select(ss => ss.s).ToList();
```

You can get more information about query-syntax and Extension method in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43579030/linq-to-sql-and-where-is-the-choice-for-all-database/43579558#43579558) answer.